# How do I get Auto Increment on my Id variable?

Tags: java, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Component {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id ;
```

I only get null on component.id

Comment: That is because you have not assigned any value to your allocated variable id.

Comment: Component.getId() will be null until the insert statement to the database, which only happens when the persistence context is synchronized with the database - essentially when flush is called or the transaction is committed. Make sure also that your reference to the entity is a managed reference, as JPA will update the managed instance with the ID, but not a detached instance. Ie if you use em.merge, it will update the entity is passes back, not necessarily the one you pass into it.

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`